# Trigger rebuild if header changes

Tags: scons

I have non system headers, which I use to compile a program via SCons. Problem is they sometimes change but SCons does not seem to scan for changes in the headers at all.
Is there a way to tell SCons to scan the headers for changes?

Comment: Start here: http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1220.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about c/c++, SCons should always scan the header files, assuming the include paths have been correctly set to do so.

If the include paths have been specified with the `CPPPATH` construction variable, then the include files in that path will be scanned for changes. The include paths specified with this variable **should not have** the `-I` prepended, as SCons will do that in a portable manner.

This variable can be appended to as follows:

```
env = Environment()
# These paths WILL BE scanned for header file changes
env.Append(CPPPATH = ['path1', '/another/path', 'path3'])
```

If the include paths have been specified in the `CCFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` construction variables, then the include files in that path will ***not*** be scanned for changes. The include paths specified in either one of these variables **must have** the `-I` prepended. This approach is beneficial when specifying system header include paths that will most likely never change, thus speeding up the build process.

Paths can be appended to the CXXFLAGS variable:

```
env = Environment()
# These paths will NOT be scanned for header file changes
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = ['-Ipath1', '-I/another/path', '-Ipath3'])
```

[Here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a5025.html) is a list of the rest of the SCons construction variables.